# Django with oauth2 for REST API

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I created project for ORM based web service API calls for my iOS application, I want to call each API calls in secure way. I chose REST framework with oAuth2 for access token creation.
 I surfed in google to find a best tutorial for creating secure API calls , but nothing helped me to resolve my problem.
 What i done so far is,

> Python with Django project and application created.
>   Created model and views for my application.

Need help and guidance for secure API calls to GET,POST my datas.

Answer (score 1):

You can make secure the api calls by passing the access-token with every get or post request.The access-token can be send either through query-params or with the HTTP_AUTHORISATION_HEADER.Also use TokenAuthentication for verifying the access-token validity.
For setting TokenAuthentication as default for all api calls add the given line to settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
)
}
```

For using default settings send token as:

```
Authorisation : Token #211341342
```

Comment: i used  'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication' ..which  one is more secure?

Comment: i also want to know few things:1.Every tutorial used admin -> users for every users..What is the reason behind it? 2.In my app registration types will be app login, facebook login . I prefer to main my app users in separate table..will it work?

Comment: OAuth2Authentication is required only if you are trying any third party logins.Rest Frameworks' token authication is secured.

Comment: Django creates a user table and all users, be it a superuser or any normal user resides in the same table.Mostly admin is used so as to use the basic settings for permission and group. 2. yes you can use another table for users if you want to, just have to make a few changes accordingly.Django will treat it as normal model but you have to make it function as User table.

Comment: i followed this tuorial to setup..> http://httplambda.com/a-rest-api-with-django-and-oauthw-authentication/

Comment: so the setup is complete, but the facebook integration will require you to follow facebook oauth docs. It will require you to create a facebook app, and follow the instructions.    https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3

Comment: Hi @prateek thanks for your support..I stucked in this line..owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name="beers")..Due to this line migration doesnt create 'beer' table

Comment: If this s not good ,,could you suggest me some other websites

Comment: The related_fielld is used for backward foreign-key relationship. Here is beers is not a model ,so no table would be created.Here 'beers' is the Manager name that returns all instances of the first model.

Comment: Try django docs for best help , apart from that there are sites like tangowithdjango.com.